# Plugin to add features to "build automatically" and "build all" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, build

I need to write a plugin in java that would add some custom features to the "build automatically" and "build all" options in eclipse. Where could I get more information about the functionality of builds in eclipse and how to modify it with plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an incremental project builder for this. Use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point to define your builder.

An example builder (as shown in the documentation):

```xml
<extension id="coolbuilder" name="Cool Builder"
           point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders"> 
  <builder hasNature="false"> 
     <run class="com.xyz.builders.Cool"> 
        <parameter name="optimize" value="true"/> 
        <parameter name="comment" value="Produced by the Cool Builder"/> 
     </run> 
  </builder> 
</extension>
```

If this extension was defined in a plug-in with id "com.xyz.coolplugin", the fully qualified name of this builder would be "com.xyz.coolplugin.coolbuilder".

For more information see the [Incremental Project Builders](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_builders.htm) section of the Eclipse help.